# Why is silicon used in laser ablation experiments?

Tags: laser

I have recently began reading into papers regarding laser ablation, and more often than not, silicon-based products seem to be the basis of the inquiry.

What properties or uses does silicon present that make it popular?

Works in question:
https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/conference-proceedings-of-spie/9740/974017/Ablation-of-silicon-with-bursts-of-femtosecond-laser-pulses/10.1117/12.2212609.short?SSO=1

https://itp.uni-frankfurt.de/~jeschke/papers/AppSurfSci197198p839.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for one Si is the foundational building block of the computing world. The semiconductor industry relies heavily on this element. Laser ablation offers an affordable, high precision method for optimizing Si-based technology through cutting Si wafers/making inscriptions. Photonic circuits can also be written in bulk Si using direct laser writing (although this is not ablation).